# CSS and responsive header/navigation issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive header with navigation but I am having difficulty with my design and placement of links etc. I have essentially 2 rows.

My top row is to be 3 links placed to the far right. The second row is my main Company name to the left, and to the far right I will have 3 navigation links. I also have a company logo I want placed at the far left which floats over both rows.

I am not a css expert and what I have so far appears to be moving in the right direction but I am stuck on why both of my navigation Unordered lists are at the end of everything when they appear to be nested correctly.

Also I need to make this responsive at some point so the secondary row navigation items collapse into a **"hamburger icon"**. If anyone can lend some pointers on what I have it is appreciated.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navContainer {
  width: 100 %;
  height: 105 px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.logo {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  float: left;

  overflow: hidden;
  left: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.bottomBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.companyName {
  color: white;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.topNavigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.topNavigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}

.topNavigation li {
  float: right;
}

.topNavigation li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topNavigation li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation li {
  float: right;
}

.navigation li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Google_Chrome_for_Android-_Android_5.0_Logo.png">


<div class="topNavigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#news">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="bottomBar">
  <span class="companyName">

    <h3>My Company Name Goes Here </h3>
  </span>


  <div class="navigation">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my project on jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/masAndrew/0apmmfLm/4/

Comment: use media queries

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it for you i think: 
    https://jsfiddle.net/0apmmfLm/6/

what you need is to move the

```
 div class="topNavigation">
     ul>
       li><a href="#news">Link 1</a></li>
       li><a href="#contact">Link 2</a></li>
       li><a href="#about">Link 3</a></li>
  /ul>

    /div>
```

to the top of the logo